# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) not returning all values to array (Excel 2013)

Tags: arrays, excel, autofilter

I have a range with 170000 rows in it. I'm filtering column A for a single value and returning the corresponding values in column B.

I want these values to dump into an array so I can quickly toss them into a dictionary (with the key being the value I filtered column A with).

The problem is that `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is acting inconsistent.

If I do the same test on a smaller range, the values dump into the array just fine. But with a range as large as mine, it only returns the first value in the range. Also, I can use the same line to copy to another sheet. I just can't get it to populate the array.

```
foo = ws1.Range(tbl1Name & "[ID]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Works with small ranges, but returns only the first result in a range as large as mine (less than 50 results.) foo becomes an array containing all the variables.

```
ws1.Range(tbl1Name & "[ID]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Range("A1")
```

Works with the large range and copies all the relevant data successfully.

So my question: How do I populate the array without the extra step of copying to a blank worksheet when autofiltering a large table range? (Excel 2013)

Comment: You could always try a loop.

Comment: I see loops were used to get around a row count limitation in previous versions, but I shouldn't need a loop for this according to everything I've read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: requires a reference to "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" (should be near the top of the list of available references).  Or add a userform to your project and that will auto-add the reference (you can then remove the form...)

This should work for a single column:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng, txt As String, cb As New DataObject, arr

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng.Copy
    DoEvents
    cb.GetFromClipboard
    txt = cb.GetText
    arr = Split(txt, vbCrLf)
    Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)

End Sub
```

If you had multiple columns you'd need to loop over each element of  `arr` (splitting its value on tab) and transfer the values to a 2-d array.

Comment: Getting a break on `code` Dim cb As New DataObject, and I don't see Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library in my references list...

Comment: Solution is to add a UserForm and the reference is automatically added.